# If $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges to a real value L, then $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ converges to $L$.

Tags: real-analysis

To prove:
If {$a_n$} is a sequence of positive real numbers, and the sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges to a real value L, then $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ converges to $L$.

Now I'm having trouble proving this. I tried the following:
Suppose that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ does NOT converge to value L. Then there is an $\epsilon$ such that there exists an $n_1>n_0$ for any $n_0$ such that:
$|\sqrt[n]{a_n}-L|\ge\epsilon$.

Then for that same value $n_1$ we still know:
$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-L|<\epsilon$

It follows $|\sqrt[n]{a_n}-L|>|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-L|\ge\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-L$

Now take a look at 2 different situations: 
a) $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ converges to a value greater than $L$: then 
$\sqrt[n]{a_n}-L>\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-L$ for certain $n_1$ that still satisfies the above conditions.

$\sqrt[n]{a_n}>\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

$a_n^{n+1}>a_{n+1}^n$

Now as $n$ approaches $\infty$, $a_{n+1}\rightarrow La_n$.
So 
$a_n\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} a_n^{n} \ge \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} L^na_n^n$
$a_n \ge L^n$

I have no idea what I'm doing anymore.. Can someone please help :(

Also this was an exercise in a chapter concerning Cauchy's root and ratio test, but I don't see a way to employ that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$
Here is a more direct approach. Take $\eps>0$ and suppose $L-\eps<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<L+\eps$ for $n\geq N$. Then
$$a_n=a_1\frac{a_2}{a_1}\frac{a_3}{a_2}\dots\frac{a_{N}}{a_{N-1}}\frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N}\dots\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}.$$
We can bound all but a fixed number of terms. Show that after taking $n$th roots  the other terms become insignificant.

Comment: So $a_n<a_1\frac{a_1}{a_2}...(L+\epsilon)^{n-N)}$ and $\sqrt[n]{a_n}<\sqrt[n]{a_1\frac{a_1}{a_2}...(L+\epsilon)^{n-N)}}$ which gives by squeeze theorem $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} \le \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1\frac{a_1}{a_2}...(L+\epsilon)^{n-N}}$

Comment: @QuestionMaker Precisely. Can you find the limit you have on the RHS? Note that $N$ is fixed once $\varepsilon$ is fixed.

Comment: The RHS limit should be equal to $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1\frac{a_1}{a_2}...\frac{a_N-1}{a_{N-2}}} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{(L+\epsilon)^{n-N}}$. Now the left limit clearly goes to 1, as all under the square root is just a constant.

Comment: The right limit equals the limit of $(L+\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N}{n}}$ Now again since $L+\epsilon$ is just a constant we look at the power, which goes to $1$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. So the limit equals $L+e$. Now using the squeeze theorem we can do the same with a limit using $L-\epsilon$ and then we prove that the the $n$th root of $a_n$ converges to $L$. Correct?

Comment: @QuestionMaker Actually, since in the RHS limit we let n go to infinity, the limit is just $L+\varepsilon$. Other than that, all is correct.

Comment: Which step are you talking about?

Comment: @QuestionMaker Actually nvm, I've misread a part of your comment. It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}\ln(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n})=\ln(L)$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k})}{n}=\ln(L)$$

using Cesaro sequence.

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1})}{n}=\ln(L)$$

Yes, you can conclude.

Comment: Thanks for your response but we've never covered a Cesaro sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Let us first prove the following:

> **Lemma.** If $(a_n)$ is convergent to $\ell$, then $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k\right)$ is also convergent to $\ell$.

**Proof.** Let $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: $$\forall n\geqslant N_1,|a_n-\ell|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$
Let $n\geqslant N_1$, using triangle inequality, one has: $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k-\ell\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a_k-\ell)\right|\leqslant\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1}|a_k-\ell|+\frac{(n-N_1+1)}{n}\varepsilon.$$
Since $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1}|a_k-\ell|}_{\textrm{constant}}\rightarrow 0$, there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: $$\forall n\geqslant N_2,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1}|a_k-\ell|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$
Furthermore, since $\displaystyle\frac{n-N_1+1}{n}\rightarrow 1$, there exists $N_3\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: $$\forall n\geqslant N_3,\frac{n-N_1+1}{n}\leqslant 2.$$
Finally, for all $n\geqslant\max(N_1,N_2,N_3)$, one has: $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k-\ell\right|\leqslant 3\varepsilon.$$
Whence the result. $\Box$

From this lemma, one derives the following:

> **Proposition.** If $(a_n)$ is such that $(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ converges to $\ell$, then $\displaystyle\left(\frac{a_n}{n}\right)$ converges to $\ell$.

**Proof.** Applying the lemma, one has that: $$\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a_{n+1}-a_n)\right)=\left(\frac{a_n}{n}-\frac{a_0}{n}\right)$$
converges to $\ell$. Whence the result, since $\displaystyle\left(\frac{a_0}{n}\right)$ converges to $0$ and $\displaystyle\left(\frac{a_n}{n}\right)=\left(\frac{a_n}{n}-\frac{a_0}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{a_0}{n}\right)$. $\Box$

Can you take it from here?