# Limit sequence (Un) and (Vn)

Tags: calculus

Let $~(U_{n} )~$ and $~(V_{n})~$ be two real sequences ,  such that :

$V_{n} = \frac{1}{n} (U_{1}+U_{2}+....+U_{n} )$  $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~; ~~n \in \mathbb{N}/\{0\}$

prove that if : $$ \lim _{n\to \infty} U_{n}= l$$ then : $$\lim_{n\to\infty}V_{n} = l$$

Comment: Do you have any ideas yourself? What have you tried already?

Comment: If someone find it appropriate, I can delete my answer as it is a partial copy/paste of my answer to this similar but not exact duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034899/if-fraca-n1a-n-converges-to-a-real-value-l-then-sqrtna-n-conve/). Let me know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: $$\forall n\geqslant N_1,|a_n-\ell|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$
Let $n\geqslant N_1$, using triangle inequality, one has: $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k-\ell\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a_k-\ell)\right|\leqslant\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1}|a_k-\ell|+\frac{(n-N_1+1)}{n}\varepsilon.$$
Since $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1}|a_k-\ell|}_{\textrm{constant}}\rightarrow 0$, there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: $$\forall n\geqslant N_2,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1}|a_k-\ell|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$
Furthermore, since $\displaystyle\frac{n-N_1+1}{n}\rightarrow 1$, there exists $N_3\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: $$\forall n\geqslant N_3,\frac{n-N_1+1}{n}\leqslant 2.$$
Finally, for all $n\geqslant\max(N_1,N_2,N_3)$, one has: $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k-\ell\right|\leqslant 3\varepsilon.$$
Whence the result.

Comment: but why $ \epsilon$ and $3\epsilon$ are equivalent ?

Comment: Not to be rude, but you should probably rehearse your lessons, this is a pretty standard fact that multiplicative constants before $\varepsilon$ are irrelevant. I could have chosen $N_1,N_2$ and $N_3$ such that each quantity was less that $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ which would have resulted to a final inequality with $\varepsilon$. Keep in mind that if $\varepsilon$ can be chosen as small as I want, then $3\varepsilon$ can be as small as I want too.